# Update EntityFramework to 6.1.1 and delete all refs to 6.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

i want to Update Entity Framework to 6.1.1 and delete all refs to 6.1 in my current project. can someone help me in a step by step procedure, how to do it? i am new to entity framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to run command

> Update-Package EntityFramework

in your Package manager console window in visual studio (View -> Other windows -> Package manager console) - make sure you have right project seleted in dropdown within this window. It will update the package, remove the old one, fix references and resolve dependencies. Magic :)